# staggeredgridlayoutmanager HORIZONTAL fill rows first

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, staggeredgridlayout

I'm trying to achieve in Android a list of views that will look like this:
[image]

Couple of specific behaviours which made this a problem for me:

- The list of views (in red), can be dynamic, and can vary in size
- The views flow should be rows then columns, as follows:

[image: ]]

I manage to achieve the first requirement with Recycleview and the layout manager StaggeredGridLayoutManager (setted the cell height on the adapter onCreateViewHolder).

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager lManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
```

But the way the layout populate itself is in the opposite direction then what I need (it populate columns then rows, as follows)

[image: 3]]

Or how it actually looks on the android app:

[image: 4]]

Is it possible to set layout manager to lay items as I need? I tried other solutions like putting all the available views in a tablelayout, then toggle visibility, but it has it's limitations as well, and I prefer the recycleview solution.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: I eventually dropped the recyclerview and created the Imageviews programmatically (calculating the dimensions of each view).
It's not perfect, but it gets the job done...
Hope it helps.